# jquery html() changes not visible after calling another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

A function used to insert bbcodes into a textfield breaks a jquery click function that makes use of the html() method.

If the jq click function gets called after the tag function, changes made by html() won't display on the view page. In Firebug I can see that changes are applied they just won't get rendered.

jquery function that breaks:

```
$('.ev').on("click", function(){

$(this).val() ?
$('#replytext').load("/quote.php",{ "id" : $(this).val() }) :
$('#replytext').html('');

});
```

the tag function that breaks the jquery function is [here](http://aktuell.de.selfhtml.org/artikel/javascript/bbcode/).

Any hints/suggestions?

Think like that: Click the quotebutton -> click the tag button. Now if you click the quote or no-quote button again the content should change to quote or empty but it remains like:
quote[tag][/tag].

Firebug shows the reseted content.

Something freezed. If I load a quote and insert a tag and load the quote again to reset the tags and try to use the insert tag function again the insert tag function still inserts tags but this time the newly inserted tags have no effect on the html displayed in Firebug. The insert function breaks the viewed textarea (if the jquery function is called after the tag function) and after breaking it it uses the "death textarea" but without changing the html viewed in Firebug.

**Link to a HTML pasty:**
[index.html](http://pastecode.org/index.php/view/79279327)
Edit: .val() works but .load() doesn't.

Comment: @idor_brad there is a condition. If val is empty `?` do something `:` else.

Comment: How about giving a jsfiddle to work with...

Comment: If you can provide the html too it will be helpful. your code apparently depends on the value on '.ev' while executing. If '.ev' has no value and when you initialized it with an empty '#replytext' div then of course it will not render anything because html('') will clear everything in the target ( which means you are clearing an empty div )

Comment: Thats what I want it to do. If there is a value use load(), else reset the content with html(''). No problem. The problem is not that the function doesn't work. The problem is that the changes are not visible on the page. They get applied but the textarea won't show the new content. In webdevtools the new content is visible, the old removed. Not so on the visible page. I'll make a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

To change what's in a textarea, try using val() instead of html():

```
$('.ev').on("click", function(){
    $(this).val() ?
    $('#replytext').load("/quote.php",{ "id" : $(this).val() }) :
    $('#replytext').val('');
});
```

Comment: English isn't my native language. Maybe I sound like an amateur, but, if it would be that easy this question would not exists. The problem is NOT the function itself. Both functions, as single functions, work like they should. Just after using the insert function some problems occur. That means: Changes are applied but not rendered.

Comment: Was worth a try... If changes aren't visible, wouldn't it be a CSS/something isn't closed issue, then? If it's in the page and you can't see it, I can't think of anything else.

Comment: No. The old content remains visible while in Firebug you see the new content.

Comment: OMG... that's amazing. Would love to see that. Sorry I couldn't help :-/

Comment: If I could there would be a link to the site but I can't. No errors logged to console. No problem with unclosed tags, no css problem etc. All other JS Functions remain working.

Comment: How about this: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/reload-dom-after-injecting-form-elements — what happens if you try moving the form right inside the body (body > form)? Anything different?

Comment: Placing the form at the top (body > form) makes no difference. How to reload the dom? Added a link to a html plain/text pasty at the end of first post. May someone confirm this bug?

Comment: I would give this .val() guy one upvote but do not own enough reputation. With val() it works BUT the original code uses .load() not .html(). And .load still doesn't work after Tag insertion.